# Can't list all user emails in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to show a list of user emails in my user profile template, which seems like a really simple thing to do, but I can't get anything to display.

I've tried using `{{ email }}` in my loop, but it just returns the current users email a bunch of times.

I've also used `{{ emailAddress.email }}` which doesn't return anything.

My user profile template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <title>{% block title %} | {{ username }}{% endblock %}</title>

    <h2>{{ username }}</h2>
    <p><b>Location: </b>{{ user.profile.location }}</p>
    <p><b>Email: </b>{{ email }}</p>

    <p>
        {% for emailAddress in emailList %}
            {{ user.email }}
        {% endfor %}
    </p>

    <a href="/accounts/profile/">Edit Profile</a>

{% endblock content %}
```

My user profile view:

```
def loggedin(request):
    return render_to_response('loggedin.html',
                             {'username':request.user.username,
                              'user':request.user, 'email':request.user.email,
                              'emailList':User.objects.values_list('email', flat=True)})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something's wrong with your `for` loop.

```
{% for emailAddress in emailList %}
    {{ user.email }}
{% endfor %}
```

You are looping through `emailList` and every element is assigned to a variable `emailAddress`. Your loop should look like this.

```
{% for emailAddress in emailList %}
    {{ emailAddres }}
{% endfor %}
```

Note that `emailList` is already a list of emails so you don't need to do `emailList.email`.